# Why does this exercise need a case distinction?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I previously solved the equation $e^{e^z}= 1$. The result I get is

$$ z = \ln( 2 \pi ) + \ln(i) + \ln(k) = \ln(2 \pi) + {\pi \over 2}i + \ln(k)$$

where $k \neq 0$.

I was told that I needed to make a case distinction for $k < 0$ and $k > 0$ but it is not clear to me why.

If $k$ is negative then $\ln(k) = \ln(-1) + \ln(|k|) = i\pi + \ln(|k|)$. But the $i \pi$ is already contained in $\ln(k)$ if $k$ is negative.

> Why does one need to make a case distinction in the solution of this
>   equation?

Comment: Well, sure, but the you could have just written $\ln(2\pi i k)$. Presumably, your teacher wants it written as $a+bi$ where $a,b$ are expressions known to be real.

Comment: For k< 0, those logarithms don't even exist!  So you do **not** need to "make a case distinction for k<0 and k>0" but you **do** need to specify that  "$k\ge 0$".

Comment: @user247327 The logarithms exist, for the purpose of using logarithms to solve equations. (In which case, logarithms are multivalued functions.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No, there is no teacher. I am reading a book and solving the exercises.

Comment: Then the book is the teacher. :) @student

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't know what to do. Is it truly more correct to make a case distinction?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but the book won't tell me about whether I need to make a case distinction or not! :-)